# What is the difference between Auto Generate and Auto Increment Build Number?

Tags: delphi, build, version

I am using Delphi XE3. In project’s version information, I see there is a “Auto Increment Build Number” and a “Auto Generate Build Number” option. What is the difference between these two, I have read the manual but cannot find any difference. I think both of them will just increase the build number by 1 each time I invoke the build command for the project, is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they both apply only for application build (not compilation), but they are semantically different.

**Auto generate build number** option produces **x.x.d.s** version number, where **d** is the number of days since 1/1/2000 and **s** number of seconds since midnight divided by 2 (applies to Delphi XE3 for Win32 & Mac OS X target platforms and may differ for different Delphi versions and platforms).

**Auto increment build number** option only increments build number **b** in **x.x.x.b** version number by value 1.

Official description you may find in [**Version Info topic**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Version_Info).